# Htaccess rules: How to redirect to specificp page only if content inside a folder doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this issue (I also searched through many threads but couldn't find the answer).

I moved a lot of content from principal domain to archives.

The action called firstaction used to have this link:
https://www.sitename.com/actions/firstaction (wordpress site)

and now it moved to
https://archives.sitename.it/actions/firstaction (totally different wordpress site).

But I still have a lot of content under [www.sitename.com/actions/](http://www.sitename.com/actions/)
So I want to redirect only if the content doesn't exist.
Only content under /actions/ folder.

I guess the redirect action could be something like
RedirectMatch "^/actions/(.*)" "https://archives.sitename.eu/actions/$1"

But I don't know how to add all the conditions I need.
I probably need to use the Skip flag S, but this goes beyond my abilities.

Thanks for your help!

p.s. it's a wordpress site under apache server.

Comment: That is nothing that can be done on protocol level, so by means of simple request rewriting. Reason is that on that level no information exists on whether some specific content exists _inside_ the wordpress application. The rewriting module can check for physical files and the like, but not for dynamic content.

Comment: If you only wanted to redirect a _few_ specific actions, then `"^/actions/(firstaction|secondaction)"` would do the job - alternation between multiple values via `|`. But that is nothing you want to write or maintain for dozens or more, and is probably not something you should "punish" the webserver with at this level either.